# Error with ValidateCreditCard function in my Javascript Cart with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

when i click the Pay Now button in the Chrome console i see this error and nothing happens. I really need your help guys because my site is good, i need only to fix this error. Thanks in advance! Feel free to contact me for any incomprehension! Also you can find over here one photo of the error : [Photo of Error in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbbFJ.png)

```
//order_process.php

session_start();

$total_price = 0;

$item_details = '';

$order_details = '
<div class="table-responsive" id="order_table">
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr>  
            <th>Prodotto</th>  
            <th>Quantità</th>  
            <th>Prezzo</th>  
            <th>Totale</th>  
        </tr>
';

if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
{
 foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
 {
  $order_details .= '
  <tr>
   <td>'.$values["product_name"].'</td>
   <td>'.$values["product_quantity"].'</td>
   <td align="right">€ '.$values["product_price"].'</td>
   <td align="right">€ '.number_format($values["product_quantity"] * $values["product_price"], 2).'</td>
  </tr>
  ';
  $total_price = $total_price + ($values["product_quantity"] * $values["product_price"]);

  $item_details .= $values["product_name"] . ', ';
 }
 $item_details = substr($item_details, 0, -2);
 $order_details .= '
 <tr>  
        <td colspan="3" align="right">Totale</td>  
        <td align="right">€ '.number_format($total_price, 2).'</td>
    </tr>
 ';
}
$order_details .= '</table>';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Ordine</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.creditCardValidator.js"></script>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <style>
  .popover
  {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 800px;
  }
  .require
  {
   border:1px solid #FF0000;
   background-color: #cbd9ed;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <br />
   <span id="message"></span>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Inserisci i dati per completare il tuo ordine.</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <form method="post" id="order_process_form" action="payment.php">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8" style="border-right:1px solid #ddd;">
        <h4 align="center">Dati Personali</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label><b><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf2bc;</i> Titolare Carta <span class="text-danger">*</span></b></label>
               <input type="text" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" class="form-control" value="" />
               <span id="error_customer_name" class="text-danger"></span>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <label><b><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf003;</i>  Email <span class="text-danger">*</span></b></label>
            <input type="text" name="email_address" id="email_address" class="form-control" value="" />
            <span id="error_email_address" class="text-danger"></span>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <label><b><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf041;</i> Indirizzo <span class="text-danger">*</span></b></label>
            <textarea name="customer_address" id="customer_address" class="form-control"></textarea>
            <span id="error_customer_address" class="text-danger"></span>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
             <div class="form-group">
              <label><b>Città <span class="text-danger">*</span></b></label>
              <input type="text" name="customer_city" id="customer_city" class="form-control" value="" />
              <span id="error_customer_city" class="text-danger"></span>
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
             <div class="form-group">
              <label><b>CAP <span class="text-danger">*</span></b></label>
              <input type="text" name="customer_pin" id="customer_pin" class="form-control" value="" />
              <span id="error_customer_pin" class="text-danger"></span>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
             <div class="form-group">
              <label><b>Stato </b></label>
              <input type="text" name="customer_state" id="customer_state" class="form-control" value="" />
             </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
             <div class="form-group">
              <label><b>Nazione <span class="text-danger">*</span></b></label>
              <input type="text" name="customer_country" id="customer_country" class="form-control" />
              <span id="error_customer_country" class="text-danger"></span>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
           <hr />
           <h4 align="center">Inserisci la carta di Credito.</h4>
           <div class="form-group">
                  <label><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf09d;</i> Numero Carta <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" name="card_holder_number" id="card_holder_number" class="form-control" placeholder="1234 5678 9012 3456" maxlength="20" onkeypress="" />
                  <span id="error_card_number" class="text-danger"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                   <label>mese di Scadenza</label>
                   <input type="text" name="card_expiry_month" id="card_expiry_month" class="form-control" placeholder="MM" maxlength="2" onkeypress="return only_number(event);" />
                   <span id="error_card_expiry_month" class="text-danger"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                   <label>Anno di Scadenza</label>
                   <input type="text" name="card_expiry_year" id="card_expiry_year" class="form-control" placeholder="YYYY" maxlength="4" onkeypress="return only_number(event);" />
                   <span id="error_card_expiry_year" class="text-danger"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                   <label>CVC</label>
                   <input type="text" name="card_cvc" id="card_cvc" class="form-control" placeholder="123" maxlength="4" onkeypress="return only_number(event);" />
                   <span id="error_card_cvc" class="text-danger"></span>
                  </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <br />
        <div align="center">
         <input type="hidden" name="total_amount" value="<?php echo $total_price; ?>" />
         <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
         <input type="hidden" name="item_details" value="<?php echo $item_details; ?>" />
         <input type="button" name="button_action" id="button_action" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="stripePay(event)" value="Pay Now" />
        </div>
        <br />
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4 align="center">Details:</h4>
        <?php
        echo $order_details;
        ?>
       </div>
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>

function validate_form()
{
 var valid_card = 0;
 var valid = false;
 var card_cvc = $('#card_cvc').val();
 var card_expiry_month = $('#card_expiry_month').val();
 var card_expiry_year = $('#card_expiry_year').val();
 var card_holder_number = $('#card_holder_number').val();
 var email_address = $('#email_address').val();
 var customer_name = $('#customer_name').val();
 var customer_address = $('#customer_address').val();
 var customer_city = $('#customer_city').val();
 var customer_pin = $('#customer_pin').val();
 var customer_country = $('#customer_country').val();
 var name_expression = /^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i;
 var email_expression = /^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/;
 var month_expression = /^01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12$/;
 var year_expression = /^2017|2018|2019|2020|2021|2022|2023|2024|2025|2026|2027|2028|2029|2030|2031$/;
 var cvv_expression = /^[0-9]{3,3}$/;

 $('#card_holder_number').validateCreditCard(function(result){
  if(result.valid)
  {
   $('#card_holder_number').removeClass('require');
   $('#error_card_number').text('');
   valid_card = 1;
  }
  else
  {
   $('#card_holder_number').addClass('require');
   $('#error_card_number').text('Numero Carta Invalido');
   valid_card = 0;
  }
 });

 if(valid_card == 1)
 {
  if(!month_expression.test(card_expiry_month))
  {
   $('#card_expiry_month').addClass('require');
   $('#error_card_expiry_month').text('Data Errata');
   valid = false;
  }
  else
  { 
   $('#card_expiry_month').removeClass('require');
   $('#error_card_expiry_month').text('');
   valid = true;
  }

  if(!year_expression.test(card_expiry_year))
  {
   $('#card_expiry_year').addClass('require');
   $('#error_card_expiry_year').error('Data Errata');
   valid = false;
  }
  else
  {
   $('#card_expiry_year').removeClass('require');
   $('#error_card_expiry_year').error('');
   valid = true;
  }

  if(!cvv_expression.test(card_cvc))
  {
   $('#card_cvc').addClass('require');
   $('#error_card_cvc').text('Data Errata');
   valid = false;
  }
  else
  {
   $('#card_cvc').removeClass('require');
   $('#error_card_cvc').text('');
   valid = true;
  }
  if(!name_expression.test(customer_name))
  {
   $('#customer_name').addClass('require');
   $('#error_customer_name').text('Nome Errato');
   valid = false;
  }
  else
  {
   $('#customer_name').removeClass('require');
   $('#error_customer_name').text('');
   valid = true;
  }

  if(!email_expression.test(email_address))
  {
   $('#email_address').addClass('require');
   $('#error_email_address').text('Indirizzo Email Errato');
   valid = false;
  }
  else
  {
   $('#email_address').removeClass('require');
   $('#error_email_address').text('');
   valid = true;
  }

  if(customer_address == '')
  {
   $('#customer_address').addClass('require');
   $('#error_customer_address').text('Inserisci Indirizzo');
   valid = false;
  }
  else
  {
   $('#customer_address').removeClass('require');
   $('#error_customer_address').text('');
   valid = true;
  }

  if(customer_city == '')
  {
   $('#customer_city').addClass('require');
   $('#error_customer_city').text('Inserisci Città');
   valid = false;
  }
  else
  {
   $('#customer_city').removeClass('require');
   $('#error_customer_city').text('');
   valid = true;
  }

  if(customer_pin == '')
  {
   $('#customer_pin').addClass('require');
   $('#error_customer_pin').text('Inserisci CAP');
   valid = false;
  }
  else
  {
   $('#customer_pin').removeClass('require');
   $('#error_customer_pin').text('');
   valid = true;
  }

  if(customer_country == '')
  {
   $('#customer_country').addClass('require');
   $('#error_customer_country').text('Inserisci Nazione');
   valid = false;
  }
  else
  {
   $('#customer_country').removeClass('require');
   $('#error_customer_country').text('');
   valid = true;
  }


 }
 return valid;
}

Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_JKDlpKvWn3oe1nIwl75D9pC400hFQsqUwu');

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response)
{
 if(response.error)
 {
  $('#button_action').attr('disabled', false);
  $('#message').html(response.error.message).show();
 }
 else
 {
  var token = response['id'];
  $('#order_process_form').append("<input type='hidden' name='token' value='" + token + "' />");

  $('#order_process_form').submit();
 }
}

function stripePay(event)
{
 event.preventDefault();

 if(validate_form() == true)
 {
  $('#button_action').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#button_action').val('Payment Processing....');
  Stripe.createToken({
   number:$('#card_holder_number').val(),
   cvc:$('#card_cvc').val(),
   exp_month : $('#card_expiry_month').val(),
   exp_year : $('#card_expiry_year').val()
  }, stripeResponseHandler);
  return false;
 }
}


function only_number(event)
{
 var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
 if (charCode != 32 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
 {
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}

</script>
```

Comment: where is your ValidateCreditCard function?

Comment: I have a  jquery.creditCardValidator.js in my JS Folder, you mean this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP states it as fixed.